# How to connect to Hive server on VMware from Tableau on my desktop?

Tags: hadoop, hive, tableau-api

This is my first time using Tableau to talk to a Hadoop data source.

My computer configuration:

> Desktop: Win7+Tableau9.3.5, 192.168.2.20
>
> Hadoop 2.7.2 + Hive 2.0 on CentOS7 on VMware (same machine with Win7)
>   192.168.112.150

I can ping from my desktop to the Hive server which is on a node on VMware.

In my Tableau on my desktop, I set the data source as HiverServer2 where I provided the credential.

I was declined access with an error below:

[image]

Can anyone help me sort it out?

Thank you very much.

Comment: from the screenshot , error - 10060 , seems to be issue with permission ,if you are using hortonworks sandbox, can u please try authentication type as 'User name' and user name as 'hue' , refer this link - http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/how-to-install-and-configure-the-hortonworks-odbc-driver-on-windows-7/

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the latest Hive ODBC connector installed and configured with the updated CA Certification PEM file (cacerts.pem file).